# How to make a chatbot that takes input and summarizes + calculates the average before terminating and printing the results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin

I'm very new to programming, just started working my way through a Python course. I've been looking through the course material and online to see if there's something I missed but can't really find anything.

My assignment is to make a chatbot that takes input and summarizes the input but also calculates the average. It should take all the input until the user writes "Done" and then terminate and print the results.

When I try to run this:

```
total = 0
amount = 0
average = 0
inp = input("Enter your number and press enter for each number. When you are finished write, Done:")

while inp:
    inp = input("Enter your numbers and press enter for each number. When you are finished write, Done:")
    amount += 1
    numbers = inp
    total + int(numbers)
    average = total / amount
    if inp == "Done":
        print("the sum is {0} and the average is {1}.". format(total, average))
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 46, in <module>
    total + int(numbers)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Done'
```

From searching around the forums I've gathered that I need to convert str to int or something along those lines? If there are other stuff that need to be fixed, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem is that when the user types "Done" then the line 
`int(numbers)` is trying to convert "Done" into an integer which just won't work. A solution for this is to move your conditional

`if inp == "Done":
    print("the sum is {0} and the average is {1}.". format(total, average))`

higher up, right below the "inp = " assignment. This will avoid that ValueError. Also add a break statement so it breaks out of that while loop as soon as someone types "Done"

And finally I think you are missing an = sign when adding to total variable.

I think this is what you want:

```
while inp:
    inp = input("Enter your numbers and press enter for each number. When you are finished write, Done:")
    if inp == "Done":
        print("the sum is {0} and the average is {1}.". format(total, average))
        break
    amount += 1
    numbers = inp
    total += int(numbers)
    average = total / amount
```